# PHP: comma separated string to html elements in the while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create radio buttons from a comma separated string which is stored in the MYSQL database.

However, I only get the last value of the comma separated string thus it only creates 1 radio button when in fact it should create multiple ones as there are strings like so:

```
1,2,3,4
```

my PHP mysql query looks like this:

```
list = "";
$sql2 ="SELECT * FROM table";
$query2 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql2);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query2); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $column = $row["column"];


             $drawes ="";
             $mark=explode(",", $Draw);
             foreach($mark as $out) {
             $drawes = '<label for="one">
             <input type="radio" id="one" name="duration" value="1" />
             '.$out.'
             </label>';
   }


list .= '<div style="width:100%; height:auto; border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC; padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;">
'.$drawes.'
</div>';

}
}
```

and I `echo $list;` on my page but there is only get 1 radio button on my page with the last value of the string like so:

```
<label for="one">
<input type="radio" id="one" name="duration" value="1" />
4
</label>
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing an assignment to `$drawes` in the loop. The current contents of the variable get overwritten.

Seems like you want to *concatenate* to the existing value.

The PHP concatenation assignment operator is  "**`.=`**".

```
$a = 'this';
$a .= 'and something else';
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are too many errors in your code. I have rewritten the parts I could test. the sql bit is not tested and I assume you are pulling the correct data.
compare my code to yours and you will see there were some wrong variables passed and also concatenation missing as well.

```
$list = "";
$sql2 ="SELECT * FROM table";
$query2 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql2);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query2); // count the output amount

if ($productCount > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    { 
        $column = $row["column"];

        $drawes = "";
        $mark = explode(",", $column);
        foreach($mark as $out)
        {
            $drawes .= '<label for="one">'.$out.'</label>
            <input type="radio" id="one" name="duration" value="'.$out.'" /><br>';
        }

        $list .= '<div style="width:100%; height:auto; border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC; padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;">'.$drawes.'</div>';
    }
}
```